# Sparklyr R with apache arrow fails, terminated unexpectedly: object 'as_tibble' not found

Tags: r, sparklyr, apache-arrow

I am trying to use sparklyr with [arrow](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arrow/index.html) to increase performance as seen for example [here](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2019/01/25/r-spark-improvements/#transforming), however running into errors.

Here is a (hopefully) reproducible example:

```
# Prepare session and data
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
config <- sparklyr::spark_config()
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(master = "local", config = config)
mtcars_sp <- dplyr::copy_to(sc, datasets::mtcars, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Using sparklyr without arrow works fine:

```
if ("arrow" %in% .packages()) detach("package:arrow")
mtcars_sp %>% sparklyr::spark_apply(function(df) df) %>% collect()
```

However, adding arrow to the mix and running the same produces errors:

```
library(arrow)
mtcars_sp %>% sparklyr::spark_apply(function(df) df) %>% collect()
```

The error message does not seem too helpful, but looking at the worker log I see:

> ERROR sparklyr: RScript (6891) terminated unexpectedly: object 'as_tibble' not found

Relevant sessioninfo:

- R version 3.6.0, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
- Packages: arrow_0.14.1, dplyr_0.8.3, sparklyr_1.0.1
- Spark version 2.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a newer version of `sparklyr` available, 1.0.2. It looks like there are [some changes](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/pull/2065) in that release that are needed to work with `arrow` 0.14.x. `sparklyr`'s [continuous integration](https://travis-ci.org/rstudio/sparklyr) with the latest version of `arrow` is passing.